# SVG mask line animation with transparent background

Tags: svg, css-animations, mask, svg-animate

I am trying to to highlight a word in HTML5 using a SVG masking technique.

This is the CSS code I am using to achieve the animation on the SVG path:

```
  @keyframes dash {
    from {
      stroke-dashoffset: 530;    
    }
    to {
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;    
    }
  } 

  .shape path {
    stroke-dasharray: 530;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;  
    fill: white;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .shape.active path {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: dash .5s ease-in forwards;
  }
```

Overall, it works well. However, it shows a white fill background while the animation is played:

[image]

How can I make this transparent so it can work on any background colour?

Here is a link to the code where you can see the animation in action: https://codepen.io/willhalling/pen/QWpXpQa

**EDITED:** I've updated codepen link to include @enxaneta solution

Comment: 1. in css remove .shape path{fill:white}; 2: In svg add fill="white" to the path inside the mask; 3. for the masked path change fill="white" to fill="none"